# Flywheel design equation (angular speed)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, torque, flywheels

What value of average angular speed (ω avg) should we take while designing the flywheel out of the varying speeds of engine depending on its acceleration. And should we just assume Cf(co-eff. of speed fluctuation) according to our application or how is it? [image: Attached equation for flywheel design]

Comment: doesn't the engine and flywheel run at the same RPM?

Comment: @jsotola some engines had 2 balance shafts as well as a crank...

Comment: @SolarMike the flywheel would still be connected to the crankshaft ... the balance shaft is for cancelling vibrations

Comment: what value of ω avg should I put in this equation out of engine various angular speeds?

Comment: When we were working out the primary and secondary forces we picked various engine speeds - 500rpm, 850, 1000, 2000 and even max rpm. Depends what you want to find out...

Comment: All of the speeds the engine will run at.

Comment: But how can one create one flywheel after putting all the speeds. A unique flywheel is to be Designed for an engine and a unique value of angular speed is required to put in this equation to design it. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: What type of engine are you considering? What is its intended use? Is for a vehicle or is it for some other case that demands a more steady operation?

Comment: Yeah a motorbike engine whose RPM varies from 1000 to 6000.